# Know the exact number of executions of a random loop in JMeter

Tags: jmeter

[image]

This is a part of my test plan. Inside the loop controller and throughput controllers, a random number is been generated.

[image]

[image]

I am saving the amount of generated number in the loop controller in "11-12". But the problem is because the throuput controllers also are generating randomly, the sum of throughput controllers is not exactly 100.

So for example, if the generated number of the loop controller is 30, after passing to throughput controllers, the total number this loop is executing is not 30 (maybe 25 or 35).

Is there any way I can find the total number this loop is executing? (considering the randomness of loop controller and randomness of throughput controllers)

Answer (score 0):

Normally you should have the same number of loops and the same sequence of calls because test needs to be [repeatable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Repeatability)

So the general recommendation is to avoid "random" number of loops and the order of requests execution.

If you're implementing a very specific scenario and repeatability is not the key I think you can reconsider the way you're generating the random number of loops.

For example if you're using [__Random() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__Random) - it has 3rd parameter: the name of [JMeter Variable](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) where to store the generated value.

So if you change this function:

```
${__Random(11,12,)}
```

to this one:

```
${__Random(11,12,numberOfLoops)}
```

it will not only generate the random number between 11 and 12 but it will also store the generated value into `${numberOfLoops}` JMeter Variable

[image]

More information on JMeter Functions concept: [Apache JMeter Functions - An Introduction](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-functions-introduction)

Comment: We actually need this randomness. The problem is not only the randomness of the loop controller but also the randomness of throughput controllers. I updated my question. Can you please check it again? Thanks.